# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" Path has been set

Tags: clojure, slf4j

I am trying to run the simple code below from [https://neanderthal.uncomplicate.org/articles/getting_started.html#overview-and-features]

I have already updated my PATH as indicated in [https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder]

Math Kernel Libraries 2018 already installed.

file project.clj

```
 (defproject math "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
 :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
             [uncomplicate/neanderthal "0.22.1"]
             [info.sunng/ring-jetty9-adapter "0.12.2"]]  
   :plugins [[lein-with-env-vars "0.1.0"]]
  :env-vars {:DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/opt/intel/mkl/lib:/opt/intel/lib"}

 :aot [math.core]
 :main math.core)
```

file core.clj

```
(ns math.core
(:use [uncomplicate.neanderthal core native]))



(def x (dv 1 2 3))
(def y (dv 10 20 30))
(dot x y)
```

I am getting the error below:

```
 Compiling math.core
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
details.
Syntax error compiling at (core.clj:8:1).
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling at (core.clj:8:1).
```

.................
.................

```
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  C:\Users\ippok\AppData\Local\Temp\neanderthal-mkl- 
  0.21.07551967567311097171.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.
   ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
```

my Path includes:

```
   C:\Users\ippok\Jars\jar_files
   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\java\jarext\slf4j
```

Classpath

```
  C:\Users\ippok>java -classpath
   Error: -classpath requires class path specification
```

Comment: off topic:
to silence the SLF4J messages, see https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/11/clojure-logging/ (TLDR; add this dependency to `project.clj`: `[ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.1.3"]`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Neanderthal but there seems to be a number of problems here:

- This environment variable is declared in UNIX style: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/opt/intel/mkl/lib:/opt/intel/lib"` but you seem to be running on Windows because of your other error.

I think you copied the example from [lin-alg-app](https://github.com/viesti/lin-alg-app) but [according to the docs](https://neanderthal.uncomplicate.org/articles/getting_started.html#requirements) that example uses that environment variable when running under Mac OS. For Windows you want something like the following in your `project.clj`:

```
 :env-vars {:PATH "/Users/ippok/DLLs"}
```

Otherwise, adding the path to the DLLs in the PATH environment variable, like running the following in `cmd.exe` before running Leiningen:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;/Users/ippok/DLLs
```

... assuming that you've installed the native libraries in `C:\Users\ippok\DLLs`.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this put the dll files in PATH (set PATH) but is it a problem with MKL dlls or it is a problem with jar files. 
Is this considered an intuitive installation?